# Saber de donde viene la redireccion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo dos acciones en un controlador (aunque también podría ser de diferentes controladores) y si una redirige la otra con un `RedirectToAction` o `RedirectToRoute` o `Redirect`, hay alguna forma de saber desde donde viene la redireccion en el otra acción?

Es decir, si la acción A tiene un `RedirectToAction('B')`, en la acción B puedo saber si viene desde A o desde otro lado?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En la Request tienes la propiedad **UrlReferrer** que te indica exactemente eso.

Si es un Redirect, esa propiedad debería estar cubierta. Si es un Transfer entonces creo que no.

De todas formas, esa propiedad no es muy fiable porque depende del navegador que es el que la envía y otros motivos. Si necesitas algo así para volver a una página concreta, lo mejor es que envies en el QueryString la url anterior igual que se hace cuando una página no autenticada te redirige a la página de login.